# Gridview onItemClickListener not register

Tags: java, android, gridview, click

I'm trying to make a popup menu appear when he user clicks on an item in the gridview, but the click is not registering. Here is my code in its simplest form (added some more blocks):

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);


    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popupMenu.show();

        }
          });
```

I read a couple of posts here in stack overflow which said to post this in my main_activity.xml as well:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

but the click is still not registering. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: This code should work. Did you try something like this: `public void onItemClick(...){Log.d("tag", "Click success");...};` ?

Comment: Show how you build the adapter.

Comment: Seems like issue with building the adapter. Also, try removing the popup and use log or Toast to check if onclick works after changing the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


                   else if(position == 0)//Here 0 is theFirst item index in gridview.
                   {
                       // Starting new intent FEES

                       final CharSequence[] items={"Standard Wise Fees","Paid Fees"};


                       AlertDialog.Builder builder3=new    AlertDialog.Builder(Home_Student.this);
                      TextView myMsg = new TextView(Home_Student.this);
                          myMsg.setText("Fees Details");
                          myMsg.setTextSize(20);  myMsg.setHeight(100);  
                          myMsg.setHeight(100);

                          myMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                          myMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


                          //set custom title
                           builder3.setCustomTitle(myMsg);


                    builder3.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    builder3.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                      @Override

                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if(items[which].equals("Standard Wise Fees"))
                      {
                          Intent i = new Intent(Home_Student.this, Fees_Standard.class);//

                            startActivity(i);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Intent i = new Intent(Home_Student.this, Fees_Student.class);//

                            startActivity(i);
                      }
                    }

                    });

                      builder3.show();

                   }






                }
            });
```

Hope It may help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
BaseAdapter baseObj = /* Object class for Grid View Setting */;
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.customerListGrid);
gridView.setAdapter(baseObj);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicking for \n"      +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Comment: hi! I am already using an adapter, which I added to my block of code above, but it's still not working :( my adapter is similar to the one from this tutorial which I found some users linking here in SO http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: @LevLeetian: Thats perfect! Thats how i use too. But try using a toast or log to check if the issue is with onclick not being called or the popup menu not openning.